# How to move plot bars together

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I was given some help on how to keep the width of bars constant regardless of how many are plotted here: [How to fix bar width in this matplotlib plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44340637/how-to-fix-bar-width-in-this-matplotlib-plot). When I vary the bar width as a function of the number of bars plotted (as in the plot on the far right) the red and blue bars no longer stay together. How can this code be modified such that the red and blue bars are together in the last plot?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# make some dummy data
scores_reading = np.random.randint(50,100,10)
scores_math = np.random.randint(50,100,10)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,5))
bar_width = 0.35
index = np.arange(10)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,4,1)
ax1.bar(index, scores_reading, bar_width, fc='b', edgecolor='none')
ax1.bar(index+bar_width, scores_math, bar_width, fc='r', edgecolor='none')
ax1.set_xlim(0,10)
ax1.set_title('Original - 10 scores')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,4,2)
ax2.bar(index[:5], scores_reading[:5], bar_width, fc='b', edgecolor='none')
ax2.bar(index[:5]+bar_width, scores_math[:5], bar_width, fc='r', edgecolor='none')
ax2.set_title('Original - 5 scores')

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(1,4,3)
ax3.bar(index[:5], scores_reading[:5], bar_width, fc='b', edgecolor='none')
ax3.bar(index[:5]+bar_width, scores_math[:5], bar_width, fc='r', edgecolor='none')
ax3.set_xlim(0,10)
ax3.set_title('Changed limit - 5 scores')

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(1,4,4)
ax4.bar(index[:5], scores_reading[:5], bar_width/2., fc='b', edgecolor='none')
ax4.bar(index[:5]+bar_width, scores_math[:5], bar_width/2., fc='r', edgecolor='none')
ax4.set_title('Changed width - 5 scores')

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I highly doubt that you have put any effort into understanding the solution to the previous question. The bar position of the red bars is shifted by some amount `x`, the bar width is `y`, so there is a space of `x-y` between the bars. Reducing this is simple math (`x-y = 0` -> `x=y`). I would therefore consider this question a dublicate of the previous one.

Comment: I'm not contesting your marking of this question as a duplicate, perhaps the majority of people on this site would be able to understand why the earlier answer led to red and blue bars that did not touch in the last graph. However, I will say that I did put effort into understanding the solution, and I asked a few different programmers for help, and no one knew right away. So, I just want to bring attention to the fact that what is obvious to you is not obvious to everyone.

Comment: And I'm not saying that the solution should be obvious. However, the solution of the previous question has provided you with a comparisson of different parameters to play with. As those parameters chosen in the last plot obviously do not give you the desired result, there is no point of just copying the past solution here. Instead one would have expected to see some attempt for a different solution, in the sense of "In the previous answer the parameters are chosen as .... Now I tried to change them to ... in order to remove the spacing, but this has the effect of ... instead of ... ."